# How to convert excel file into mdf file

Tags: mysql

i have an exel file. i want to change this file into mdf formmat. Plz tell me the full procedure, how i can convert this file. i m using excel 2003 nd sql server 2000.

Comment: Have you tried to import data from excel to sqlserver?
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert. The mdf is a SQL server file. You can import data from Excel to SQL server. There is a Data Import Wizard in SQL server to get you started.